# Никак не могу открыть файл

Tags: c++, файлы

Писал упражнение, написал простейший ввод из файла, а он не работает. Свёл к этому, оно, как ни странно тоже не работает, ещё и выдаёт  ошибки C4566 и C4129 (в строке 9). Имя и расположения файла верные, перемещать в другие папки пробовал (адрес в коде, разумеется, менял), пробовал другой диск и даже другую машину... Я в замешательстве. Вывод, разумеется, всегда "Error".

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        string a;
        fstream file;
        file.open("‪D:\input.txt");
        if (file.is_open()) {
            getline(file, a);
            file.close();
            cout << a;
        }
        else
            cout << "Error";
        system("pause");
        return(0);
    }
```

Comment: `"‪D:\\input.txt"` - escape the escaper

Comment: Имя файла целиком скопировано из свойств - там один слеш, но ваш вариант я попробовал: всё равно файл не открылся, хоть ошибки компиляции и ушли.  P.S: (В файле просто 2 строки чисел, на всякий). Прошу прощения за тупость.

Comment: "равно файл не открылся" - откуда Вы знаете?

Comment: Потому что в противном случае вывод не был бы "Error", т.к. выражение file.is_open() было бы истинным.

Comment: Всё ещё мучаюсь

Comment: У Вас между открывающей кавычкой в имени файла и буквой D стоит какой-то странный символ (невидимый). (Юникод - зло xD). Наберите руками кавычки и имя файла и будет Вам счастье. Наверное. Т.е. у меня так программа работает. И да, кроме записи "D:\\input.txt", еще обычно можно применять прямые слеши как разделители - тогда не придется ничего экранировать: "D:/input.txt".

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Всё хор. Я и не думал о невидимом символе. Мораль: копирование пути к файлу из свойств - зло ))

Comment: А вот при однобайтовых кодировках таких дешевых разводов не было :-). (Вообще, мне про этот символ намекнул редактор при попытке сохранить в cp1251). Да, на будущее, избегайте, по возможности, использовать "вкомпилированные" абсолютные пути к файлам. Относительные пути чаще работают правильно (например, при переносе программы на другой компьютер - диска Д может вообще не оказаться же ;-)  ).

Comment: А еще, я только сейчас обратил внимание на сообщение C4566  - Вам же компилятор открытым текстом намекал, что в строке с именем используются юникодные символы там, где их быть не должно...

Answer (score 2):

Если вам не помог двойной обратный слеш, то возможно вы напутали что-то с путями. Попробуйте так:

```
 int main() {
        string a;
        fstream file;
        file.open(".\\file.txt");//Указываем путь относительно папки проекта,
                                 //если уверены, что файл лежит в корне папки
                                 //можете просто написать имя фала 
                                 //file.open("file.txt");
        if (file.is_open()) 
        {
            while (!file.eof())//Пока не конец файла, так как у вас более одой строчки в файле
            {
                getline(file, a);
                cout << a << endl;
            }
            file.close();//Закрываем после считывания всех строк
        }
        else
            cout << "Error";
        system("pause");
        return(0);
    }
```

Comment: И если и так не работает, то вероятно решение вопроса лежит в области каталога откуда запускается программа, и что она считает корневой директорией, если запуск из IDE, то как правило корнем она считает корень проекта. Проверить можно командой: `getcwd(buffer, sizeof(buffer));`